# Why Double::compareTo can be used as an argument of Stream.max(Comparator<? super T> comparator)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, comparator, method-reference

The api for `Stream.max` requires an argument of type `Comparator<? super T>`, and for `Comparator`, the only abstract method is

```
int compare(T o1, T o2)
```

but `Double::compareTo`, the `compareTo` api is

```
public int compareTo(Double anotherDouble)
```

why just provide one argument, so why can `Double::compareTo` use as argument of Stream

```
Optional<T> max(Comparator<? super T> comparator)
```

Comment: as I find streamObj.max(Double::compareTo) can run successfully

Comment: You've selected the wrong answer as the correct one. It's basically a "me-too" answer of the first correct answer provided by Andronicus.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I understand your position. I had trouble understanding this when I was learning about it. The answer given with reference to the Language Specification is great, but it would not have helped me when I was struggling to work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below `MyComparator` implement a `Comparator`. It takes two arguments.
It's the same as the lambda expression `(d1,d2) -> d1.compareTo(d2)`
and the same as the method reference `Double::compareTo`

The method reference is the same because `d1` is a `Double`, so Java assumes the `compareTo` method is to be called on the first `Double`. The other argument `d2` becomes the argument for the method called. This is also very nicely explained by @Andronicus.

The 3 variants in this example are equivalent:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Comparator;

class MyComparator implements Comparator<Double> {
  public int compare(Double d1, Double d2) {    // (d1,d2) ->
    return d1.compareTo(d2);                    // d1.compareTo(d2)
  }
}

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<Double> list = List.of(1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6,7.7);

      Double maxClass =
        list.stream()
            .max(new MyComparator())
            .orElse(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);

      Double maxLamdba =
        list.stream()
            .max((d1,d2) -> d1.compareTo(d2))
            .orElse(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);

      Double maxMethodreference =
        list.stream()
            .max(Double::compareTo)
            .orElse(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Check out the oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#type). This is a reference to an **instance** method. This means, it can be considered as `BiFunction`, that takes the instance as the first argument.

In [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) (15.13.3) we can read, that:

> If the form is ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier, the body of the invocation method similarly has the effect of a method invocation expression for a compile-time declaration which is the compile-time declaration of the method reference expression. Run-time evaluation of the method invocation expression is as specified in §15.12.4.3, §15.12.4.4, and §15.12.4.5, where:
>
> - The invocation mode is derived from the compile-time declaration as specified in §15.12.3.
> - **If the compile-time declaration is an instance method, then the target reference is the first formal parameter of the invocation method.** Otherwise, there is no target reference.
> - If the compile-time declaration is an instance method, then the arguments to the method invocation expression (if any) are the second and subsequent formal parameters of the invocation method. Otherwise, the arguments to the method invocation expression are the formal parameters of the invocation method.

The interesting part is bolded by me.

Comment: sorry but not understand..Double::compareTo is an instance method? what is "target reference is the first formal parameter of the invocation method...." means?

Comment: It's not a static method, it's invoked on an instance, hence "reference to an instance method". And the second question - the reference method is equivalent to `(d, otherD) -> d.compareTo(otherD)`, which means, that an instance on which the method is invoked is the first parameter of `BiFunction`. I hope it's clear